# How to directly read application.property value into another configuration xml file in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, classpath, application.properties

I have specified some webservice endpoints into applicaiton.properties file as below
**application.properties**

```
config.middleware.soap.service.endpoint.sample=http://xxx.xxx/sample/
```

Now i want to directly use those values into another configuration file that is in my case root-context.xml file for creating soap class using jax-ws client. but the property is never understood by spring boot if i refer it from applicaiton.properties value. why not? if i directly provide the endpoint it works. what is the simplest way to use application.properties file values into anther configuration file?
**root-context.xml**

```
<jaxws:client id="sampleClient" serviceClass="com.sample.wsdl.sample"
        address="${config.middleware.soap.service.endpoint.sample}">

        ...
    </jaxws:client>
```

in my case both the root-context and application.properties file reside in src/main/resources folder.. so i assume both the files gets loaded on classpath when the applcation boot strap.

Comment: What do you mean "directly read into..."?

Comment: i just want to use a property value that i have declared in the application.properties file in another xml configuration file as mentioned in the question above. I thought any property declared in application.property file would be accessible like a env property and can be directly used in another config xml also .... how can i do that.. what is the smartest way possible.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked finally when i used it in below mentioned way

```
<jaxws:client id="acctInqClient" serviceClass="com.ge.india.capital.wsdl.spine.AcctInq"
        address="#{environment['config.middleware.soap.service.endpoint.sample']}">
```

provided, i declared one property in the name config.middleware.soap.service.endpoint.sample in the applicaiton.properties file.

But i would like to know why only ${config.middleware.soap.service.endpoint.sample} didn't work. thank you.